# Android 5 (Lollipop) Wifi Landing Page now in modal dialog/view without redirect to homepage function any more

Tags: android, redirect, android-wifi, router, dd-wrt

The Wifi login with Android 5 has changed fundamentally. The redirect (e.g. with a DD-WRT NoCatSplah landing page) is not directly ignored, but it closes after the user clicks on accept-button (now displayed in a new modal view not any more in android for chrome browser).

I think there are a lot of companies affected because they show on redirect (post splash) page local information, time remaining without paying in Wifi network or ads. 
E.g.: big Wifi providers or hotels....

Does anyone know a specification-link for this new Android 5 behavior? Or how to handle it to open e.g. a chrome tab for redirection after clicking on accept-button to enter the Wifi network (old behavior - workaround)?!
E.g. Window.open does not work in this new "modal view".

On my DD-WRT router I use NoCatSplash with the following splash.html:

```
<html>
<p><b><font size="10">Welcome to my WiFi</font></b></p>

<form name="login" method="post" action="http://192.168.1.1:5280/">
<input type="hidden" name="accept_terms" value="yes" />      
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://my-homepage.html">
<input type="hidden" name="mode_login">
<input type="submit" value="I agree, connect me to WLAN!">
</form>
</html>
```

I also tried to allow the IP addresses on router (wallet garden) which try to connect to internet when modal view appears (I think they check if the splash.html should be shown in modal view or not). But no luck.

It would be optimal to make the old behavior happen on Android 5. The splash.html should be shown only if a user opens the mobile web browser and tries to open a website the first time. (no notification on Android and modal view).

For further information about this see also:
http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/638688-splash-pages-redirect-on-android-lollipop-5